# How to process messages from DLQ with EventBridge [EventBridge -> Lambda]?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

The architecture for a service includes the following:

[image]

[S3 event notification -> EventBridge rule triggered -> **same** message sent to both Lambdas]

There is a DLQ configured for the EventBridge and a DLQ for each Lambda. The former DLQ is for issues with delivery of the message to the Lambdas and the latter DLQs are for issues with the Lambdas itself.

Let's say Lambda A processes the message successfully but Lambda B does not and after exhausting the retry policy, Lambda B sends the message from the EventBridge to its own DLQ since this error is due to a code issue with the Lambda B function.

After updating the code for Lambda B, what is the recommended approach to send the message in the DLQ back to the EventBridge for Lambda B to process it again without sending this message to Lambda A.

Note: The EventBridge sends the same S3 notification message to both Lambdas.

Comment: Probably need to use Step Functions to orchestrate your logic. This would be the first choice to consider.

Comment: You'd probably want to redrive it specifically to Lambda B, not all the way back to Event Bridge

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! We are likely just manually re-driving the EventBridge message from the DLQ to Lambda B.

Comment: How do you redrive the records in Lambda B DLQ back to Lambda B?